# Is there a secret setting that keeps me from painting textures

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am sorry if there is already a post like this but the only things I've seen are tutorials and explanations on how to set-up the start file or something similar for texture painting. 
My problem is that i can't bring it to work no matter what. I've made sure that I am on the right paint slot, UV-Map and object. It all doesn't work. The weird thing is that this only occurs on my project so I believe there is a hidden setting or something that I must've clicked by accident that keeps me from progressing further. Is there a way to reset only the project settings? Without messing with my global preferences?

I have uploaded a video on Youtube which shows what I mean.
[Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/ZnH6kaMLMHA)

Comment: You could just take a screenshot of your 3d viewport with Toolshelf opened when in Texture paint mode. In general this is most likely the problem with brush settings. In this case, set the Blend mode to e.g. Mix instead of Color, second, get rid of the (probably) empty texture in the texture mask settings (Texture rollout).

Comment: Ok. Nice! I had it set to color. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

It was a really simple solution - change *Blend* mode of the brush to *Add* (in this case) instead of *Color* and remove texture mask with empty texture from the *Texture* rollout.

[image]